# Converter CODA objeto para CSV

Tags: r, csv

Estou usando "Hierarchical Modelling of Species Communities (HMSC)", e usei o comando "convertToCodaObject" para visualizar as informações empíricas do modelo (ex.: média e sd). Entretanto, estou com dificuldades para salvar os dados em CSV para fazer alguns plots, por exemplo:

As médias e o desvio padrão para "S1" em relação aos "C2", "C3" e "C4"

S= espécie,
C= preditor

Exemplo do retorno das informações empíricas do modelo:

```
Iterations = 50100:150000
Thinning interval = 100 
Number of chains = 2 
Sample size per chain = 1000 

1. Empirical mean and standard deviation for each variable,
   plus standard error of the mean:

                                                         Mean        SD
B[(Intercept) (C1), Crax.fasciolata (S1)]           2.921e+00 4.144e+00
B[dist.water (C2), Crax.fasciolata (S1)]           -2.372e-04 3.009e-04
B[elevation (C3), Crax.fasciolata (S1)]            -2.306e-02 2.250e-02
B[api (C4), Crax.fasciolata (S1)]                  -4.552e-02 3.647e-02
B[(Intercept) (C1), Crypturellus.sp (S2)]          -7.328e-02 3.676e+00
B[dist.water (C2), Crypturellus.sp (S2)]           -1.022e-05 1.772e-04
B[elevation (C3), Crypturellus.sp (S2)]            -6.738e-03 2.129e-02
B[api (C4), Crypturellus.sp (S2)]                  -3.093e-02 1.537e-02
B[(Intercept) (C1), Cuniculus.paca (S3)]           -9.618e-02 2.852e+00
B[dist.water (C2), Cuniculus.paca (S3)]            -7.985e-05 1.608e-04
B[elevation (C3), Cuniculus.paca (S3)]             -7.255e-03 1.700e-02
B[api (C4), Cuniculus.paca (S3)]                   -9.612e-03 1.032e-02 

2. Quantiles for each variable:

                                                         2.5%        25%
B[(Intercept) (C1), Crax.fasciolata (S1)]          -4.743e+00 -1.019e-01
B[dist.water (C2), Crax.fasciolata (S1)]           -8.597e-04 -4.310e-04
B[elevation (C3), Crax.fasciolata (S1)]            -7.313e-02 -3.830e-02
B[api (C4), Crax.fasciolata (S1)]                  -1.543e-01 -5.840e-02
B[(Intercept) (C1), Crypturellus.sp (S2)]          -6.618e+00 -2.389e+00
B[dist.water (C2), Crypturellus.sp (S2)]           -3.151e-04 -1.339e-04
B[elevation (C3), Crypturellus.sp (S2)]            -5.893e-02 -2.061e-02
B[api (C4), Crypturellus.sp (S2)]                  -6.003e-02 -4.047e-02
B[(Intercept) (C1), Cuniculus.paca (S3)]           -5.745e+00 -2.160e+00

                                                       97.5%
B[(Intercept) (C1), Crax.fasciolata (S1)]           1.259e+01
B[dist.water (C2), Crax.fasciolata (S1)]            2.861e-04
B[elevation (C3), Crax.fasciolata (S1)]             1.980e-02
B[api (C4), Crax.fasciolata (S1)]                   2.021e-03
B[(Intercept) (C1), Crypturellus.sp (S2)]           8.715e+00
B[dist.water (C2), Crypturellus.sp (S2)]            3.752e-04
B[elevation (C3), Crypturellus.sp (S2)]             3.157e-02
B[api (C4), Crypturellus.sp (S2)]                  -1.462e-03
B[(Intercept) (C1), Cuniculus.paca (S3)]            5.586e+00
B[dist.water (C2), Cuniculus.paca (S3)]             2.359e-04
B[elevation (C3), Cuniculus.paca (S3)]              2.618e-02
B[api (C4), Cuniculus.paca (S3)]                    1.026e-02
```

Como posso salvar os dados em CSV no qual eu consiga incluir os valores de média e sd: 0.025 e 0.95, para cada "S" por cada "C"?

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70).